# python selectors based on a socket

Tags: python, sockets

I feel like I am missing some important information on how python [selectors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html) work. I am trying to use them with a socket. Once the socket is "registered" to the selector I start to loop and "select" on the selector (A). If that returns something the selector is "registered" with the data of the `MsgEnvelope` class with the code below (B). This is the point I am stuck at in the `MsgEnvelope` class I have a read and a write method, but I don't see that being called. (Note I have logs saying client connected but nothing after that)

```
    def accept_wrapper(self, tmp_sock):
        connect, address = tmp_sock.accept()
        logging.info(f"accepted connection from {address}")
        connect.setblocking(False)
        message = MsgEnvelope(self.selector, connect, address) # <<< B
        self.selector.register(connect, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=message)

    def receive(self):
        for key, mask in self.selector.select(timeout=None):   # <<< A
            if key.data is None:
                self.accept_wrapper(key.fileobj)
            else:
                yield key.data
```

So when the "server" registers the EVENT.READ with the message I do not understand how I can read the bytes in the `MsgEnvelope` class?

TLDR: What methods do I need in a class that is used as the data keyword in the `selector.register` method. As the documentation say

> data is an opaque object.

Wat?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I misunderstood how I should use the selector. The `selector.select` will yield a "key" and a "mask". The key data property is the MsgEnvelope in my case and the mask is the bits to see if it was a read or a write.